# Session variable never equals value

Tags: python, flask

When my session.usertype is equal to "AgencySU" it never ever gets thru the first if statement
I'm I doing something wrong?
thanks

```
{% if session.usertype=="AgencySU"%}
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "layout2.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem, what is `session`? `userType`? what framework are you using? Try displaying the value of `session.usertype` before the condition, clearly it's different from what you were expecting.

Comment: yes so sorry i'm using Flask

Comment: Oscar, thanks for your reply, the session prints exactly the value "AgencySU" so getting the value is not the problem but the if statement is not working and I wonder why?

Comment: the session gets its value just fine because I'm able to do a print

Answer (score 0):

The flask `session` variable is a dictionary. So you need to use `session["usertype"]`.

The following code should work:

```
{% if session["usertype"] == "AgencySU"%}
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "layout2.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

If that doesn't work, you might also have to pass the session variable into the template.

Comment: Varun thanks so much for your reply, that did not work either, and let me ask you something, If you have to pass the variable doesn't that defeats the intend and purpose of a session?